# Transforming ADODB.RecordSet xml using XSLT 1.0, unable to rename element z:row

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0

I need to transform xml produced by ADODB.RecordSet into another xml. Everything works as expected except this one element.

XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:s="uuid:BDC6E3F0-6DA3-11d1-A2A3-00AA00C14882" xmlns:dt="uuid:C2F41010-65B3-11d1-A29F-00AA00C14882" xmlns:rs="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:rowset" xmlns:z="#RowsetSchema">
<xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="/xml">
    <xsl:element name="xml">
        <xsl:element name="rows">
            <xsl:for-each select="/xml/rs:data/z:row">
                <xsl:copy>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
                </xsl:copy>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="@*">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="name()='z:row'">
            <xsl:element name="row">
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:element name="{name()}">
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="z:row">
    <row>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </row>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Input XML:

```
<xml xmlns:s="uuid:BDC6E3F0-6DA3-11d1-A2A3-00AA00C14882" xmlns:dt="uuid:C2F41010-65B3-11d1-A29F-00AA00C14882" xmlns:rs="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:rowset" xmlns:z="#RowsetSchema">
<rs:data>
    <z:row skip1="A" number="1" id="Vend Slot 2"/>
    <z:row skip1="A" number="2" id="Vend Slot 3"/>
</rs:data>
</xml>
```

Actual Output:

```
<xml>
<rows>
    <z:row xmlns:s="uuid:BDC6E3F0-6DA3-11d1-A2A3-00AA00C14882" xmlns:dt="uuid:C2F41010-65B3-11d1-A29F-00AA00C14882" xmlns:rs="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:rowset" xmlns:z="#RowsetSchema">
        <skip1>A</skip1>
        <number>1</number>
        <id>Vend Slot 2</id>
    </z:row>
    <z:row xmlns:s="uuid:BDC6E3F0-6DA3-11d1-A2A3-00AA00C14882" xmlns:dt="uuid:C2F41010-65B3-11d1-A29F-00AA00C14882" xmlns:rs="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:rowset" xmlns:z="#RowsetSchema">
        <skip1>A</skip1>
        <number>2</number>
        <id>Vend Slot 3</id>
    </z:row>
</rows>
</xml>
```

Expected Output:

```
<xml>
<rows>
    <row>
        <skip1>A</skip1>
        <number>1</number>
        <id>Vend Slot 2</id>
    </row>
    <row>
        <skip1>A</skip1>
        <number>2</number>
        <id>Vend Slot 3</id>
    </row>
</rows>
</xml>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work. Here is my working Xslt.

```
<xsl:transform version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:z="#RowsetSchema">
<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="*">
    <!-- remove element prefix (if any) -->
    <xsl:element name="rows">
        <xsl:for-each select="//z:row">
            <xsl:element name="row">
                <!-- process attributes -->
                <xsl:for-each select="@*">
                    <!-- remove attribute prefix (if any) -->
                    <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
                        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                    </xsl:element>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```